# What's new in OSRM v5?

Tags: openstreetmap, osrm

OSRM have realesed new version, v5.

And I can't find anywhere, what's new in it?
I found new documentation of HTTP API, https://github.com/Project-OSRM/osrm-backend/blob/master/docs/http.md , but it isn't enought.

I don't know, whether it makes sense to update version. I use OSRM only for finding hiking trails on the single city.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you look at [OSRM's changelog](https://github.com/Project-OSRM/osrm-backend/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md).

5.0 brings drastic change to the HTTP API, but also lots of improvements to how instructions are generated, as well as a lot of bug fixes and other tweaks. If you're planning on continuing to use OSRM, I would recommend upgrading.